# Use jQuery to find div by background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to use jQuery to find the number of divs that are both visible, and have a background color of Green.

(Normally I'd just add a class to the div, style it green, and check for that class in jQuery but in this instance, I can't actually change the markup of the page itself in any way)

I currently have the visible div part working as  :

```
if(  // if there are more than one visible div 
    $('div.progressContainer:visible').length > 0   
){
```

I'd like to throw some kind of "and background color is green" selector in there.

```
// not legit javascript
if(  // if there are more than one visible div, and its color is green 
    $('div.progressContainer:visible[background-color:green]').length > 0   
){
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use this in more than one location frequently you could also consider writing your own custom selector (http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1055-creating-a-custom-filter-selector-with-jquery/)

```
jQuery.expr[':'].greenbg = function(elem) {
        return jQuery(elem).css('background-color') === 'green';
};
```

Then you would simply do `$('div:visible:greenbg').stuffs()`

Comment: As @SLaks pointed out this won't match `#0f0` but provides a single place for you to include all those checks.

Answer (score 11):

jQuery does not have style-based selectors (other than `:visible`), so you can't do that.

You can use `filter` instead:

```
$('div.progressContainer:visible').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('background-color') === 'green';
})
```

Note that it won't match `background-color:#0F0`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to fine tune what you're selecting like this:

```
$('div.progressContainer:visible').filter(function(){
   return $(this).css('background-color') == 'green';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do this:

```
if($('div.progressContainer:visible').css('background-color') == 'green'){
   //should equal true, if it's green
}
```